# How to subtract 2 nullable DateTimes in C#?

Tags: c#

I want to subtract 2 "datetime?" values and display the answer in number of days. The TimeSpan or ToDays methods dont work on nullable datetimes. Any other way i can do it?

Comment: How do they 'not work'? What happens when you try it? What exactly are you trying?

Comment: if they are not null you could just use Not Nullable.

Comment: @DavidHedlund the result can be a null value. I am reading 2 "datetime?" columns from a db and performing number of days between them calculation. If they are null, i either want to skip that db row or just insert null as answer.

Comment: I guess he wanted to use directly DateTime.Subtract method.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Can't you just use:

```
if(yourDateTime != null) {
   DateTime dateTime = yourDateTime.Value; // You can run .ToDays etc on this

}
```

Answer (score 7):

You need to get the [`.Value`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.nullable-1.value) property of the nullable type to access methods of the underlying value type.

Note that this will throw an exception if there is no value.

Answer (score 4):

Do it like this:

```
DataTime? a;
DateTime? b; 
TimeSpan? duration;

// Assign values to a and b...

if(a.HasValue && b.HasValue)
{
  duration = b.Value - a.Value;
}

var days = duration.GetValueOrDefault().TotalDays;
var hour = duration.GetValueOrDefault().TotalHours;
```